# Subquery filtering through extension-method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, linqkit

### Background

I'm trying to clean up my code by extracting some code into some extension methods, as shown below. I stumbled upon **LINQKit**, which has the `Expandable` functionality. I created a simple extension method `AtPointInTime`, which takes a `DateTimeOffset` as input (See code below), but I keep getting an error. What am I doing wrong (Can't find a solution in the documentation)?

### Implementation

```cs
[Expandable(nameof(AtPointInTimeImpl))]
public static IQueryable<TSource> AtPointInTime<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> query, DateTimeOffset pointInTime) where TSource : class, IBitemporal
{
    return query.AsExpandable().Where(entity => AtPointInTimeFilter<TSource>().Invoke(entity, pointInTime));
}

private static Expression<Func<IQueryable<TSource>, DateTimeOffset, IQueryable<TSource>>> AtPointInTimeImpl<TSource>() where TSource : class, IBitemporal
{
    return (query, pointInTime) => query.Where(entity => AtPointInTimeFilter<TSource>().Expand().Invoke(entity, pointInTime));
}

private static Expression<Func<TSource, DateTimeOffset, bool>> AtPointInTimeFilter<TSource>() where TSource : class, IBitemporal
{
    return (entity, pointInTime) => entity.ValidTimeFrom <= pointInTime && (entity.ValidTimeTo > pointInTime || entity.ValidTimeTo == null);
}
```

### Usage

To get all companies at a specific point in time I utilize `AtPointInTime` *(Note: Bitemporal storage solution)*.

> The `AtPointInTime` can also be called in a subquery I therefore extended my `AtPointInTime` with `Expandable`.

**Example #1**

```cs
var companies = await _dbContext.Companies.AtPointInTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow).ToList()
```

**Example #2**

```
var query = from alarm in _dbContext.Alarms.AtPointInTime(request.PointInTime)
            select new GetAlarmQueryResult
            {
                Alarm = alarm,
                Company = _dbContext.Companies.AtPointInTime(alarm.Created).SingleOrDefault(),
            };
```

### Error

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Company>
    .Where(c => (entity, pointInTime) => (DateTimeOffset)entity.ValidTimeFrom <= pointInTime && (Nullable<DateTimeOffset>)entity.ValidTimeTo > (Nullable<DateTimeOffset>)pointInTime || entity.ValidTimeTo == null
        .Invoke(
            expr: c, 
            arg1: __pointInTime_0))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: I know how LINQKit works, but I'm trying to understand why so complex solution. here. Show how do you plan to use this extension.

Comment: Hi @SvyatoslavDanyliv: I'm properly misunderstanding some LinqKit concepts. I basically just want an extension method named `AtPointInTime` which takes a `DateTimeOffset` and applies a `Where` clause. The `AtPointInTime` extension method will be used in subqueries and I, therefore, looked at `Expandable`. How can my proposal be simplified? Thanks for taking your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following implementation:

```cs
[Expandable(nameof(AtPointInTimeImpl))]
public static IQueryable<TSource> AtPointInTime<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> query, DateTimeOffset pointInTime) 
    where TSource : class, IBitemporal
{
    return query.AsExpandable().Where(entity => entity.AtPointInTime(pointInTime));
}

private static Expression<Func<IQueryable<TSource>, DateTimeOffset, IQueryable<TSource>>> AtPointInTimeImpl<TSource>() 
    where TSource : class, IBitemporal
{
    return (query, pointInTime) => query.Where(entity => entity.AtPointInTime(entity, pointInTime));
}

[Expandable(nameof(AtPointInTimeEntityImpl))]
public static bool AtPointInTime<TSource>(this TSource entity, DateTimeOffset pointInTime) 
    where TSource : class, IBitemporal
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private static Expression<Func<TSource, DateTimeOffset, bool>> AtPointInTimeEntityImpl<TSource>() 
    where TSource : class, IBitemporal
{
    return (entity, pointInTime) => entity.ValidTimeFrom <= pointInTime && (entity.ValidTimeTo > pointInTime || entity.ValidTimeTo == null);
}
```

Also `AsExpandable` can be eliminated if you configure EF Core options:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to eliminate:

This expression:

```
return (entity, pointInTime) => entity.ValidTimeFrom <= pointInTime && (entity.ValidTimeTo > pointInTime || entity.ValidTimeTo == null);
```

should likely be:

```
return (entity, pointInTime) => entity.ValidTimeFrom <= pointInTime && (entity.ValidTimeTo == null || entity.ValidTimeTo > pointInTime);
```

Having it the other way around would have it assessing the nullable property in a comparison before the null check. EF may be able to generate that, but possibly not.

Where I've used `AsExpandable` it has always been on the `DbSet`, not `IQueryable`. Try moving the AsExpandable out of the extension method and calling:

```
var companies = await _dbContext.Companies
    .AsExpandable()
    .AtPointInTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
    .ToListAsync()
```

If that works the extension method may need to be updated to work against `DbSet<TEntity>` rather than `IQueryable<TEntity>`. I doubt `_dbContext.Companies.AsQueryable().AtPointInTime(...)` would work, though it might be worth a shot? :)

Other that that it looks like it *should* work for wrapping a temporal check. If I had to hazard a guess either the AsExpandable() call within the extension rather than directly on the DbSet meant the `AsExpandable` didn't "take" in the expression builder, or the inverted condition might be getting passed as-is and bunging up the generation.

I'm assuming the Plain old manual linq expression works just fine?

```
var pointInTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

var companies = await _dbContext.Companies
    .Where(entity => entity.ValidTimeFrom <= pointInTime 
        && (entity.ValidTimeTo == null 
            || entity.ValidTimeTo > pointInTime)
    .ToListAsync();
```