# EF Cannot be translated

Tags: entity-framework, linq, graphql

i have problem with translated query, ToList(), AsEnumerable etc.

I need construct or create query which is shared.

Branches -> Customer -> some collection -> some collection
Customer -> some collection -> some collection.

Do you help me how is the best thingh how to do it and share the query.

i access to repository via graphql use projection etc.

```cs
public IQueryable<CustomerTableGraphQL> BranchTableReportTest(DateTime actualTime, long userId)
{
    var r =
    (
        from b in _dbContext.Branches
        let t = Customers(b.Id).ToList()
        select new CustomerTableGraphQL
        {
            Id = b.Id,
            Name = b.Name,
            Children =
            (
                from c in t
                select new CustomerTableGraphQL
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    Name = c.Name
                }
            )
            .AsEnumerable()
        }
    );

    return r;
}

public IQueryable<Customer> Customers(long branchId) => 
    _dbContext.Customers.Where(x => x.BranchId.Value == branchId).ToList().AsQueryable();
```

Some example how to doit and share iquearable between query

Comment: Why you have put `ToList` everywhere? Remove that and query should be translatable. If not, it needs refactoring to `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ToList` / `AsEnumerable` etc. entirely defeats the potential benefits of using `IQueryable`. If your code needs to do this rather than return an `IQueryable<TEntity>` then you should be returning `IEnumerable<TResult>` where `TResult` is whatever entity or DTO/ViewModel you want to return.

An example of an `IQueryable<TEntity>` repository pattern would be something like this:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomersByBranch(long branchId) => 
    _dbContext.Customers.Where(x => x.BranchId.Value == branchId);
```

Normally I wouldn't really even have a repository method for that, I'd just use:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers() => 
    _dbContext.Customers.AsQueryable();
```

... as the "per branch" is simple enough for the consumer to request without adding methods for every possible filter criteria.  The `AsQueryable` in this case is only needed because I want to ensure the result matches the `IQueryable` type casting. When your expression has a `Where` clause then this is automatically interpreted as being an `IQueryable` result.

So a caller calling the Repository's "GetCustomers()" method would look like:

```
// get customer details for our branch.
var customers = _Repository.GetCustomers()
    .Where(x => x.BranchId == branchId)
    .OrderBy(x => x.LastName)
    .ThenBy(x => x.FirstName)
    .Select(x => new CustomerSummaryViewModel
    {
         CustomerId = x.Id,
         FirstName = x.FirstName,
         LastName = x.LastName,
         // ...
    }).Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

In this example the repository exposes a base query to fetch data, but without executing/materializing anything. The consumer of that call is then free to:

- Filter the data by branch,
- Sort the data,
- Project the data down to a desired view model
- Paginate the results

... before the query is actually run. This pulls just that page of data needed to populate the VM after filters and sorts as part of the query. That Repository method can serve many different calls without needing parameters, code, or dedicated methods to do all of that.

Repositories returning `IQueryable` that just expose DbSets aren't really that useful. The only purpose they might provide is making unit testing a bit easier as Mocking the repository is simpler than mocking a DbContext & DbSets. Where the Repository pattern does start to help is in enforcing standardized rules/filters on data. Examples like soft delete flags or multi-tenant systems where rows might belong to different clients so a user should only ever search/pull across one tenant's data. This also extends to details like authorization checks before data is returned. Some of this can be managed by things like global query filters but wherever there are common rules to enforce about what data is able to be retrieved, the Repository can serve as a boundary to ensure those rules are applied consistently. For example with a soft-delete check:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers(bool includeInactive = false)
{
    var query = _context.Customers.AsQueryable();
    if (!includeInactive)
        query = query.Where(x => x.IsActive);
    return query;
}
```

A repository can be given a dependency for locating the current logged in user and retrieving their roles, tenant information, etc. then use that to ensure that:

- a user is logged in.
- The only data retrieved is available to that user.
- An appropriate exception is raised if specific data is requested that this user should never be able to access.

An `IQueryable` repository does require a Unit of Work scope pattern to work efficiently within an application. `IQueryable` queries do no execute until something like a `ToList` or `Single`, `Any`, `Count`, etc. are called. This means that the caller of the repository ultimately needs to be managing the scope of the DbContext that the repository is using, and this sometimes rubs developers the wrong way because they feel the Repository should be a layer of abstraction between the callers (Services, Controllers, etc.) and the data access "layer". (EF) To have that abstraction means adding a lot of complexity that ultimately has to conform to the rules of EF (or even more complexity to avoid that) or significantly hamper performance. In cases where there is a clear need or benefit to tightly standardizing a common API-like approach for a Repository that all systems will conform to, then an `IQueryable` pattern is not recommended over a general `IEnumerable` typed result.  The benefit of `IQueryable` is flexibility and performance. Consumers decide and optimize for how the data coming from the Repository is consumed. This flexibility extends to cover both synchronous and asynchronous use cases.

Comment: Nice, but you have produced different query.

Comment: The point is that if he wants to have the Repository producing a query like his original, then he should return `IEnumerable`, not `IQueryable`. `IQueryable` is suited to returning entity queries where the consumer of the query does the projection. The answer is about explaining the how's and why's of considering `IQueryable` with a Repository pattern, not shoe-horning a method that just tries to satisfy it with an `AsQueryable()` at the end. :)

Answer (score 0):

EF Core will translate only inlined query code. This query will work:

```cs
public IQueryable<CustomerTableGraphQL> BranchTableReportTest(DateTime actualTime, long userId)
{
    var r =
    (
        from b in _dbContext.Branches
        select new CustomerTableGraphQL
        {
            Id = b.Id,
            Name = b.Name,
            Children =
            (
                from c in _dbContext.Customers
                where c.BranchId == b.Id
                select new CustomerTableGraphQL
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    Name = c.Name
                }
            )
            .AsEnumerable()
        }
    );

    return r;
}
```

If you plan to reuse query parts, you have to deal with [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) and its `ExpandableAttribute` (will show sample on request)

Comment: Thank for you answer, can you send me link for documentation or do hou have some example project?

Comment: Not sure about documentation, better to post link to my similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70065880/10646316). Do not forget to configure `DbContextOptions` with `.WithExpressionExpanding()`.  Your function `Customers(long id)`, should be mapped with `[Expandable(nameof(CustomersImpl))]`. `CustomersImpl` should be static function WITHOUT parameters but return `Expression<long, IEnumerable<Customer>>`.  This expression will be injected into final query and will make EF Core happy.

Comment: Not sure that you can use `let` keyword for collections. EF Core still has weak LINQ translator.

Comment: if `Customers` is not static function you have to return as first Expression argument repository or what you have for `this` -  `Expression<CustomerRepository, long, IEnumerable<Customer>>`